# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbDatepicker"

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 4, i was trying to add datepicker while i'm using
   datepicker-popup.html I'm getting error as given below. I'm not getting what kind of 
   error 
   it is. please help me out.
    [image]

**datepicker-popup.html**

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
                    <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;" />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<hr/>
<pre>Model: {{ model | json }}</pre>
```

Answer (score 23):

Please add these two lines in your file.

> ```
> import { NgbDate, NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
> ```

and import the NgbModule.

> ```
> imports: [NgbModule]
> ```

Comment: thanks, it solves problem.  more detail: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2433

Answer (score 3):

This error means that `#d="ngbDatepicker"` is invalid, because the `DatePickerComponent` of the library does not have a `exportAs` property set to `ngbDatepicker`.

You should open the component and see the real value of `exportAs`, and use it in place of your current template variable.

### EDIT

Given you're using [Bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/demo/src/app/components/datepicker/datepicker.component.ts) (inferred from the name of your datepicker), here is the component decorator :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker',
  template: `...`
})
```

As you can see, no `exportAs` directive : this means you can't write `#d="ngbDatepicker"`.

(And if you're not using that one, consider that as the way to know if components have `exportAs` properties)

### EDIT 2

To resolve that : declare a template variable and declare it as a view child reference

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker>
```

```js
@ViewChild(NgbdDatepicker) d: NgbdDatepicker;
```

This should work. If you have several date pickers, name them in order to find them :

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d>
```

```js
@ViewChild('d', { read: NgbdDatepicker }) d: NgbdDatepicker;
```

Comment: Exactly what will be the solution ..means #d="ngbDatepicker" is not required, if yes then what will be the solution

Comment: now i'm getting :    ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (datepicker-popup.html:6)

Comment: Okay so it means you didn't import the module into yours.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

In HTML:

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" formControlName="dp" ngbDatepicker>
```

In TS:

```js
@ViewChild('NgbdDatepicker') d: NgbDateStruct;
```

Answer (score 0):

These methods are deprecated in the recent angular versions(6.0) above.

Answer (score 0):

Add NgbDatepickerModule to imports:

```
imports: [
...
NgbModuele,
NgbDatepickerModule,
...
],
```

Answer (score -1):

In my project, the problem was that I was using Angular 7, so ng-bootstrap had version 4.x.x.

Many ngb modules only work from ngb version 6 and above.