# Angular 9.1.4 will support which bootstrap version?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am updating my Angular 5 Application into Angular 9.1.4 version with latest bootstrap library(4.4.1). below is my **package.json **file.

When i am doing **prod build ** I am getting lot of error messages due to AOT compilation , how can i fix these issues ? do I need to downgrade Angular version ? ng serve working fine but no luck with prod build. can any one help me in it.

below are couple of sample error messages,

error TS-998003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngbDatepicker'.
141                   #firstDate="ngbDatepicker"

error TS-998003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngbTabset'.
2

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^9.1.4",
"@angular/common": "^9.1.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^9.1.4",
"@angular/core": "^9.1.4",
"@angular/forms": "^9.1.4",
"@angular/localize": "^9.1.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.4",
"@angular/router": "^9.1.4",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
"@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"bootswatch": "^4.4.1",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.6.11",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
"rxjs": "^6.5.4",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
"sax": "^1.2.4",
"stream": "0.0.2",
"stream-browserify": "^2.0.2",
"timers": "^0.1.1",
"timers-browserify": "^2.0.11",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"

 },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.22",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.31",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint": "^4.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "sass": "^1.24.4",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    **"typescript": "~3.8.3"**
  }
```

please let me know if any more info required…

HTML Code : `<div class="custom-date-picker">
              <div class="input-icon icon icon-calendar"></div>
              <input 
                ngbTooltip="The year dropdown in the date picker displays a range of +- 10 years from the current year. 
                  To select a year outside of this range, select the first year or last year in the dropdown."
                class="form-control custom-input-field tooltip-custom-class"
                placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" 
                [(ngModel)]="StartDatePicker" 
                ngbDatepicker
                formControlName="tentativeBenefitsEffectiveDate" 
                [displayMonths]="1" 
                [navigation]="'select'" 
                [firstDayOfWeek]="7"
                #dpStartDate="ngbDatepicker"
                autocomplete="off"
                [autoClose]="true"
                (click)="dpStartDate.toggle(); $event.stopPropagation(); closeFixOverlapDates(dpStartDate)" 
                (document:click)="closeFix($event, dpStartDate)">
              <button class="btn input-btn {{dpStartDate.opened ? 'icon-shape-reverse' : 'icon-shape'}}" tabindex="-1" 
                (click)="dpStartDate.toggle(); $event.stopPropagation(); closeFixOverlapDates(dpStartDate)" 
                type="button"></button>
            </div>`
TypeScript code :

```
    `@ViewChild('dpStartDate',{ static: true }) dpStartDate: NgbInputDatepicker;
  closeFix(event, datePicker) {
    if (event.target.offsetParent == null) {
      datePicker.close();
    } else if (event.target.offsetParent.nodeName !== 'NGB-DATEPICKER') {
      datePicker.close();
    }
  }
  closeFixOverlapDates(datePicker) {
    this.closeAllDates();
    datePicker.open();
  }
  closeAllDates() {
    this.dpStartDate.close();
  }`
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependencies also shows `ng-bootstrap` version "^1.6.3",

As per ng-bootstrap documentation, for Angular 9, you need 6.x.x. You will need to update it too.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#dependencies

**Edit:**

I'm afraid Bootstrap `Tabset` has been deprecated and you may need to refactor the code using `Nav`.

You can find the documentation at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples

As for Bootstrap `Datepicker`, make sure you have `NgbModule` or `NgbDatepickerModule` imported along with `FormsModule` in your module.

Comment: Thank you Sunil, I tried installing 6.X.X but still i am getting same error when i am running prod build.

Comment: Please check the edit and let me know. Also please post the HTML where `#firstDate="ngbDatepicker"` is used

Comment: Thank you Sunil, I have edited my html and typescript code.

Comment: No Sunil, I have imported NgbModule and NgbDatepickerModule but errors are still showing .. only when ng build --prod

Comment: I tried as suggested in below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980080/there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngbdatepicker/54349007
error is disappearing but.toggle() method and date picker passing inside closeFix() method as HTMLInpmutElement not like datepicker. I am confused what would be the solution.

Comment: Thank you Sunil, its an cache issue i feel, now its working.

Answer (score 0):

This highly because you have not imported the modules associated with that component. In Angular, even components sub-class directives, which are identified in modules.To solve this, you can do the following:

In app.module.ts;

```
import {ngbDatepickerModule, ngbTabsetModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Then add to the imports arrays

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ngbDatepickerModule, ngbTabsetModule],
})
```

Comment: Thank you Nova, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: I have imported NgbModule, NgbDatepickerModule, ngbTabsetModule but errors are still showing .. only when ng build --prod

Comment: Hi Nova, I have imported bootstrap module there is some cache issue or version issues I have taken latest and greatest working fine now.Thank you for your time and support.